# How to find how many users on Windows XP and specific version of IE in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I can't see a way of doing this in GA. What I can do is find out how many Windows users were on IE7 over a given time period, but not how many Windows XP users were on IE7.

Does anyone know how to configure GA to provide me that info? Basically what I'm looking for is the total number of users running XP who were also using either IE7/8/9. I don't mind running the three browser version queries separately and adding them for a cumulative figure but I can't even get it to refine down that far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you would need to create a segment that only includes 'Operating System Version contains XP' - Give it an appropriate name aswell.

[image: Segment]

Then when you go back to your reporting, remove the 'All Users' segment.

Click Audience > Technology > Browser & OS

[image: report]

Following this, you should be able to use the first Dimension as Browser Version, then add a second dimension which is 'Browser' - Click Internet Explorer when all browsers are displayed.

This will segment all your users to only include the XP OS
And you can see the data with two dimension of version and Browser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian, really comprehensive answer and guide. I'm working through it now and will mark as answer once done.

Comment: Hi, You use the browser dimension to find Internet explorer and when you click on IE you should be presented with the different versions. :)

Comment: Thanks, getting an error when trying to mark this as the answer. I'll keep trying. Thanks again for taking the time to create such a clear answer.